# I am looking for help on how to re-trigger the failed camunda workflows in effective way such as Batch

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I am looking for help on how to re-trigger the failed camunda workflows in effective way such as Batch..

Here is the scenario details

I have a camunda workflow which is triggered by service A via rest API. The workflow uses External task to implement the business logic to talk to service B . 
If the workflow failed because of the transient errors in service B and those workflows will be failed. If the requests are 1 or 2, those can be re-triggered manually.
But if the failed workflows are in order 10s or 100s, it will be cumbersome to do manually hence I am looking on help the options to address this..

Are there are any better ways to re-trigger the failed camunda workflows either using Camunda UI or Rest APIs or any other options?

Details  of the Camunda
- Community Edition, container image tag is: "7.11.0"

Answer (score 0):

Note: These kind of batch operations are a build in feature of the enterprise edition, so if this is a recurring use case in your business, consider upgrading to enterprise.

That being said: you can re-build this feature using either script/rest or the  java API. Basically, you create a jobQuery looking for failed instances and increase the number of retries.

Comment: Thanks Jan Galinski for the detailed response. Are you referring this API https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.9/reference/rest/job/post-set-job-retries/ ? I have tried this, but getting this  below error  message with 400 status code  {
    "type": "InvalidRequestException",
    "message": "jobIds is empty"
}   I couldnt find any instructions how to create the Job. Can you please provide more details on JobQuery API which you are referring in your response? I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: You never create jobs ... jobs are created for you when the engine has either a timer or an activity marked with "async before/after" in the model. Then you should use the jobQuery to find the job you need. I don't do REST API, so I can not help you with code samples. Maybe someone else can?