# camunda bpnm spring boot activity delegates matching is not working

Tags: spring-boot, camunda, orchestration, camunda-modeler

I downloaded the sample provided for spring micro services orchestration from [GITHUB](https://github.com/colinlucs/microservices-orchestration-amqp-example.git)

it works as the details given in the description, but now I am trying t build my own workflow and not able to map how the call flow(code gets exectued) from one activity to other activity.

In the bpnm [guide](https://dzone.com/articles/event-driven-orchestration-an-effective-microservi) it shows the first activity name as **Retrieve Shopping Cart** and second one as **Validate Address** but when I start the workflow with rest call from the below code

```
public class ShoppingCartRestController {

    @Autowired
    private ProcessEngine camunda;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{scId}/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> placeOrderPOST(@PathVariable("scId") String scId) {
        ProcessContext context = new ProcessContext();
        submitShoppingCart(scId, context);
        if (context.getError() != null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(context.getError(), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(context.getResponse(), HttpStatus.OK);

    }

    private ProcessInstance submitShoppingCart(String scId, ProcessContext context) {
        return camunda.getRuntimeService().startProcessInstanceByKey(//
                "submitShoppingCart", //
                Variables //
                        .putValue(ProcessConstants.VAR_SC_ID, scId).putValue(ProcessConstants.VAR_CTX, context));
    }
}
```

from the above I am not able to get how it delegates to retrieve address  and in turn that delegates to validate address and so on to end the flow ?

And how the process is linked from submitShoppingCart.bpmn  (Name in this and Actual classes are not matching ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 2 first: java api and process match via the processes technical id.
you see it in the "startProcessInstanceByKey" call: `submitShoppingCart` is the technical id of the process. In The modeller, you find it at the very top of the properties panel.[image]

Question 1: The camunda Java API links service Tasks to execution via JavaDelegate interfaces. So for each service task, there is a class that implements what should happen in its `execute(DelegateExecution execution)` method.

In spring projects, these delegates are in general referred to by their bean names ... in your example, the "Retrieve Shopping Card" service is backed by the `${retrieveShoppingCartActivity}` delegate. By convention, the bean name equals the class name, so look for `RetrieveShoppingCartActivity` to see what's inside.

Comment: thanks for the answer.. Is there any way to restart workflow from failed activity ?  in  my case if it is failed at state "Reserve Payment" ..  I want to restart the workflow or submit from this state instate of from the beginning

Comment: That depends ... If your service tasks are not marked with "exec async", a failure will result in a transaction rollback ... which will lead to the complete process instance rollback and thus you have no chance of restarting. If you have async execution (async before), you will see an incident in the cockpit and can reset the retry count to try again. See this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58673552/i-am-looking-for-help-on-how-to-re-trigger-the-failed-camunda-workflows-in-effec